# Join multiple phone numbers into columns: phone1, phone2, phone3

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to join multiple phone numbers to a customer for a full CSV export without having duplicate entries. The data structure I have:

**Customer**

| ID | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |
| 2 | Max | Payne |

**Phones**

| ID | CustomerId | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12345679 |
| 2 | 1 | 987654321 |
| 3 | 1 | 456789451 |
| 4 | 2 | +67987654321 |

**Desired select result:**

| ID | firstname | lastname | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 | phone4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 12345679 | 987654321 | 456789451 |  |

The amount of phone numbers is limited to 9.

Comment: Self left join?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just put all the phones in a single column:

```
select c.*, group_concat(p.number order by p.id) as numbers
from customer c left join
     phones p
     on c.id = p.customer_id
group by c.id;
```

(Note:  This assumes that `customer(id)` is the primary key of `customer`.)

If you want separate columns, you can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select c.*, 
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then p.number end) as phone_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then p.number end) as phone_2,
       . . .
from customer c left join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by p.id) as seqnum
      from phones p
     ) p
     on c.id = p.customer_id
group by c.id;
```